# Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a `.jar` file on the start up of my Linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04 server)

My script works as long as I run it inside the directory which it is in. If I try to run it outside the directory I get the error "Cannot access jarfile settasks.jar". I suppose my other script is having the same issue.

Is this possibly a script error or a permissions error? I'm completely lost and I have not found anything as of yet to resolve the issue. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Little unclear here. Is settasks.jar another file which you didn't move or is it the one you did move?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on the file and select <kbd>Copy</kbd>.

Now, say you are executing the file using **this** in the directory with the file in:

```
java -jar ./settask.jar
```

Type the beginning of the command *(`java -jar`)*, and then paste -<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - you should end up with something like this, where is specifies the full path to the file:

```
java -jar file:///home/wilf/settask/settask.jar
```

Remove the `file://` and press <kbd>↵</kbd>:

```
java -jar /home/wilf/settask/settask.jar
```

If it works, then the same command should work in your script.

*I hope this answer is OK, I think you are asking about bash scripts.*

**N.B:**

`./` tells it the command to search the directory it is currently in.

Having`file://` at the beginning means it won't work.

Comment: Yes that fixed it many thanks. Yes I was using a bash script.

Comment: you mean `java -jar "$(readlink -f settask.jar)"`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into `Unable to access jarfile` when trying to [start a Spring Boot SysVinit service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment-install.html).

It turned out the directory and content in `/srv/myapp/` had wrong ownership.

Running `sudo sh -c "chown -R myapp:myapp /srv/myapp/ && chmod -R u=rx,g=,o= /srv/myapp"` gave all relevant files and directories correct ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Starting it in the Terminal with the error

```
Unable to access unicentaopos.jar
```

The solution is more simple than the problem.

Add to the known starter the line `Path=/usr/bin/unicenta/`
and the problem is solved.
The folder `/unicenta` is of course the folder where the program is.

In that way the starter looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Unicenta
Comment=Fires up Unicenta oPOS
Type=Application
Path=/usr/bin/unicenta/
Exec=/usr/bin/unicenta/start.sh
Icon=/usr/bin/unicenta/unicentaopos.ico
```

To create the starter just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal.

Type `cd Desktop` (or Bureaublad if its Dutch) (Case sensitive)

Type `nano unicenta.desktop`. Copy and paste the mentioned code.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save is. Close is by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Type `chmod +x unicenta.desktop`.

Ready.

Comment: The OP asked for a @ startup solution and accepted a answer two years ago...

Comment: are you sure about the command `CD /Desktop`? `cd` is not `CD` and there is no Desktop directory in root.

Answer (score 0):

The message "unable to access jarfile" is misleading. If you type the jarfile name incorrectly, you still get the same message not "no such file or directory". So, if you are in the directory where the jarfile is located, first, make sure that you typed the name correctly. For example, you may have a jarfile name as xxxx.1.jar; It is usual to igonre .1. and type it is xxxx.jar; you will receive "unable to access jarfile" message, which as I mentioned is misleading.

Comment: The script runs correctly when run 'inside the directory is in'. So, the name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is like mine or not, but I say my problem and solution may help someone:
I had this error when I wanted to run my shell script to run the Java application:

```
"Unable to access jar file"
```

my problem occurred because I had made the shell script file in Windows so the file had been created with a Windows line ending (CR) while the shell script should be with a Unix line ending (LF), so the solution was changing the line ending to Unix in the Notepadd++ and I saved file and after rerun the problem was solved.