# Unable to run .Jar file for a RSPS?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm trying to run a .jar file that I've downloaded for a Runescape Private Server (I'm not trying to host, I'm just trying to play another server).

However when I run it in my terminal it says:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile
```

And if I right click and go on properties and go to 'open with' there's no java option?

But I have Java because I've ran the old school runescape client and played actual runescape.

I'm running Kubuntu, any help is appreciated!

Thank you! :)

```
$ java -jar /home/george/Ikov\client/ikov.jar
May 06, 2015 12:12:10 PM ikov_launcher.Ikov_launcher downloadNew
SEVERE: null
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at ikov_launcher.Ikov_launcher.downloadNew(Ikov_launcher.java:106)
        at ikov_launcher.Ikov_launcher.main(Ikov_launcher.java:45)
```

Comment: What command did you used in the terminal

Comment: java -jar ikov.jar

Comment: paste the output of "java -version" from terminal

Comment: (precise)george@localhost:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode

Comment: Try This one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/391310/unable-to-access-jarfile

Comment: (precise)george@localhost:~$ java -jar /home/george/Ikov client/ikov.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/george/Ikov

Comment: It didn't work :/

Comment: The problem is with your directory.  rename your foder "Ikov client" Dont leave space. try it now

Comment: Try this command "java -jar /home/george/Ikov\client/ikov.jar"

Comment: Ok thank you, so that almost worked, but I got this error:

Comment: I put it in the original question.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cd-to-a-directory-with-spaces-86701/

Comment: I changed the file name, but I got that error in the original question now.

Comment: I suggest you to purge all your java and install latest oracle java. Almost many jar application is made on the back head of oracle java. So it may works on oracle java.

Comment: Ok do you have any guide on how I do that please? :/

Comment: Let me once again confirm the link of that file.

Comment: Copy that file to Desktop

Comment: /home/george/Ikovclient/ikov.jar

Comment: I took the space out of the 'ikov client'

Comment: Try This "java -jar /home/george/Ikovclient/ikov.jar"

Comment: I got the same error again.

Comment: The jar file was started. The Exception has nothing to do with the start.

Comment: Did it worked ?

Comment: Copy the file to Desktop

Comment: It starts the download, then just stops and gives me all those exception codes

Comment: Just the .Jar or the whole folder?

Comment: Give me a download link for the JAR file.

Comment: only xxx.jar to desktop

Comment: https://ikovps.com/downloads/

Comment: @AUmarMukthar This is senseless!

Comment: @A.B. https://ikovps.com/downloads/

Comment: Thx, same error here. I will investigate it.

Comment: It's a connection problem not more

Comment: Ok thank you, does that mean there's anything that I can do to fix it?

Comment: @A.B. K you carry on

Comment: @Bunni I think so

Comment: @A.B. Oh, so I'm never going to be able to play it then. :/

Comment: @Bunni Have you tested it with Windows?

Comment: Yeah it works on a Windows Laptop that I have, but this is a chromebook and ChromeOS doesn't support java.

Comment: Thats's the problem . It seems that connections from non-Windows clients are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The connection request is rejected. This is certainly the fact that you try it on a Linux system. Based on your comments, it works with Windows. Linux is a not-supported system in this case, even if it is a Java application.

Comment: Does it work with oracle java ?

Comment: No, I have tested.